# Count records created within the last 7 days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How can I alter the query below to only select records created within the last 7 days?

```
self.favorites.count
```

This function is located in my `User` model.

```
 def calculate_user_score
    unless self.new_record?
      self.score = (self.links.count * 5) + (self.favorites.count * 0.5)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can add a `where`-condition like this:

```
self.favorites.where('created_at >= ?', 1.week.ago).count
```

And for your `calculate_user_score` method, you probably want to do that for `links` as well:

```
def calculate_user_score
  unless new_record?
    self.score = (links.where('created_at >= ?', 1.week.ago).count * 5) +
      (favorites.where('created_at >= ?', 1.week.ago).count * 0.5)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 14):

I recommend you add a scope to your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :recents, where("created_at > ?", Time.now-7.days)

end
```

Then you can do

```
self.favorites.recents.count
```

Comment: up for nice separation

Comment: I find this to be the best practice.

Answer (score 7):

In **Rails 4+**

This code seems not working:

```
"created_at > ?", Time.now-7.days
```

I tried like:

```
scope :recent, -> { where("DATE(created_at) > ?", (Date.today).to_time - 7.days) }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.links.where("created_at > ?", Time.now-7.days).count
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in Rails, you can just use the `ago` datetime methods, instead of doing weird time math.

```
scope :recent, -> { where("created_at > ?", 1.week.ago) }
```

In Rails, you can usually avoid a lot of the complicated data preparation and type-casting you might have to do in other languages / frameworks.

Re: the original post, I would probably refactor it like this:

```
# Using association extensions here to filter this down,
# the ellipses parenthetical should be whatever you're using for your
# association definition.

has_many :links ( ... ) do
  def since(last_date)
    where('created_at > ?', last_date)
  end
end
has_many :favorites (...) do
  def since(last_date)
    where('created_at > ?', last_date)
  end
end

# Don't use magic numbers; codify them for context.
LINK_SCORE_MULTIPLIER = 5
FAVE_SCORE_MULTIPLIER = 0.5

# Note this does not persist it in the database; if you want it to persist 
# you'll want to execute an update instead. However it does memoize it so multiple
# calls will pull from the in-memory cache of the object instead of re-querying it
def score(recalculate: true)
  @score ||= (links.since(1.week.ago).count * LINK_SCORE_MULTIPLIER) +
            (favorites.since(1.week.ago).count * FAVE_SCORE_MULTIPLIER)
end
```

Then you just reference it passively:

```
@user.score # runs the query and saves to memory
@user.score # pulls from memory
@user.score(recalculate: true) # re-runs the query and saves to memory
@user.save  # persists the result (assuming you have a field for :score)
```

It might require refactoring, but depending on how your data is modeled, you might be able to use a `counter_cache` to track it (this would require a `has_many`,`through` association, and the `counter_cache` would be on the joining model.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for records which could return `last 7 days` i.e. not including today. But this worked for me and it can work for `last n days`.

```
last_n_days = 7

Model.where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', Date.today-last_n_days, Date.today-1).count
```

with scope

```
scope :last_n_days, lambda {|n| where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', Date.today - n, Date.today - 1)}
```