# Count users created in last 7 days in rails ? [need help in syntax of Count]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I saw this [Count records created within the last 7 days](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8426781/692622) but still need some help in getting the syntax of COUNT right, right now I have

```
@count_users = User.count('comment')
```

which gives me Count of all comments but I need to know count of all comments made only in last 7 days or in last 1 month, but I am not able to figure out the correct syntax for it

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to use the `created_at` attribute to compare the current date.  `User.where('created_at >= ?', 7.days.ago).count('comment')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This count:

```
@count_users = User.count('comment')
```

Generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(comment) FROM "users"
```

So **unless you have a comment column** in your users table, **it is not counting the right objects**.

**If you have a Comment model**, you can use the following to count all comments created in the past 7 days:

```
Comment.where('created_at >= ?', Time.zone.now - 7.days).count # count for a week
Comment.where('created_at >= ?', Time.zone.now - 1.months).count # count for a month
```

If you want to count the Comments of a specific User, you can use this (**assuming a Comment belongs_to a User and a User has_many Comments**):

```
Comment.where(user_id: user.i).where('created_at >= ?', Time.zone.now - 7.days).count
```

Comment: comment is actually just a field in User table

Comment: So take a look at @jvnill comment on your answer ;)

Comment: actually your code worked, surprisingly it was pretty straight forward  :) thanks